# :after element not displaying after element

Tags: html, css

I am running into an issue where my vertical red line is not positioned at the end of the `.techDataInfo` container. For some reason it is placing after `.techDataInfo img`.

See the image I have below. This is how I want it to look. I also cannot get the `vertical-align: middle` to work for the red line.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

[image]

```css
.techDataBlock:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #CFCFCF;
  margin: 60px auto;
}

.techDataInfo,
.techDateTableCont {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: auto;
}

.techDataInfo {
  width: 40%;
}

.techDataInfo:after {
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  /*vertical-align: middle;*/
  background: #b82222;
}

.techDataInfo img {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}

.techDateTableCont {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="techDataBlock">
  <div class="techDataInfo">
    <h2 class="techDataBlockTitle">General Information</h2>
    <img src="https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/242ce817-97a3-48fe-9acd-b1bf97930b01/09-posterization-opt.jpg" alt="Img">
  </div>
  <div class="techDateTableCont">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Measure</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EN AW-Al Mg Si 0.5</td>
        <td>EMaterial Designation DIN EN 573</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tensile strength RM</td>
        <td>min. 245 N/mm²</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Yield Point Rp 0.2</td>
        <td>min. 195 N/mm²</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ductile yield A5</td>
        <td>min. 10%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ductile yield A10</td>
        <td>min. 8%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Moulus of elasticity E</td>
        <td>70.000 N/mm²</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hardness HB</td>
        <td>approx. 75 Brinell hardness</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Coefficient of Linear expansion</td>
        <td>23.4 x 10⁻⁶ 1/K</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: after elements appear inside at the end of the element you put it on, not after it

Comment: @Pete But it isn't displaying on the inside at the end. When this is scaled up in size, it is far away from the end of the container.

Comment: It is showing here at my place :P

Comment: @paul because you made it inline-block so it appears next to the image, which is inline - think of what would happen if you put a span next to the image tag - it wouldn't appear at the end of the tech block, it would appear next to the image tag - that's what your after element is doing

Comment: Then how do I get it to appear at the end of the container? I would do a border, but not sure if I can set the border height and then align it vertically.

Comment: you could make tech relative and position the after absolutely

Comment: @Paul, when you post code with your question, please strip the irrelevant stuff, (in your case most of the table) this makes it more readable, and easier to see your problem. Good that you added an image by the way!

Comment: @Pete Good idea. I did that and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

I think is a good place to use the flexbox properties `display:flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap` will put the elements on a new line if there is not enough space in the row.

It allows you to align the items in the center with `align-items:center` and also separate it with different criterias `justify-content: space-around|space-between`

```css
.techDataBlock:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #CFCFCF;
  margin: 60px auto;
}

.techDataInfo,
.techDateTableCont {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: auto;
}

.techDataInfo {
  width: 40%;
}

.techDataInfo:after {
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  /*vertical-align: middle;*/
  background: #b82222;
}

.techDataInfo img {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}

.techDateTableCont {
  width: 60%;
}

.techDataInfo{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-around;
 align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="techDataBlock">
  <div class="techDataInfo">
    <h2 class="techDataBlockTitle">General Information</h2>
    <img src="https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/242ce817-97a3-48fe-9acd-b1bf97930b01/09-posterization-opt.jpg" alt="Img">
  </div>
  <div class="techDateTableCont">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Measure</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EN AW-Al Mg Si 0.5</td>
        <td>EMaterial Designation DIN EN 573</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tensile strength RM</td>
        <td>min. 245 N/mm²</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Yield Point Rp 0.2</td>
        <td>min. 195 N/mm²</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ductile yield A5</td>
        <td>min. 10%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ductile yield A10</td>
        <td>min. 8%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Moulus of elasticity E</td>
        <td>70.000 N/mm²</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hardness HB</td>
        <td>approx. 75 Brinell hardness</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Coefficient of Linear expansion</td>
        <td>23.4 x 10⁻⁶ 1/K</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.techDataBlock:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #CFCFCF;
  margin: 60px auto;
}

.techDataInfo,
.techDateTableCont {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: auto;
}

.techDataInfo {
  width: 40%;
 justify-content: space-between;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 align-items: center;
}

.techDataInfo:after {
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  /*vertical-align: middle;*/
  background: #b82222;
 
}

.techDataInfo img {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}

.techDateTableCont {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="techDataBlock">
  <div class="techDataInfo">
    <h2 class="techDataBlockTitle">General Information</h2>
    <img src="https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/242ce817-97a3-48fe-9acd-b1bf97930b01/09-posterization-opt.jpg" alt="Img">
  </div>
  <div class="techDateTableCont">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Measure</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EN AW-Al Mg Si 0.5</td>
        <td>EMaterial Designation DIN EN 573</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tensile strength RM</td>
        <td>min. 245 N/mm²</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Yield Point Rp 0.2</td>
        <td>min. 195 N/mm²</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ductile yield A5</td>
        <td>min. 10%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ductile yield A10</td>
        <td>min. 8%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Moulus of elasticity E</td>
        <td>70.000 N/mm²</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hardness HB</td>
        <td>approx. 75 Brinell hardness</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Coefficient of Linear expansion</td>
        <td>23.4 x 10⁻⁶ 1/K</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```